# Variable Access in JSON Body

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a search method for domains that returns whether or not it can be registered. I am having trouble accessing the 'status' string in the returned JSON body.

Here is my AngularJS code for accessing the API:

```
hosting.searchDomain = function() {

        var domain = hosting.domain;
        var tld = hosting.tld;

        var url = apUrl + 'api/domains/available.json?auth-userid='+ resellerId +'&api-key='+ key +'&domain-name='+ domain +'&tlds='+ tld +'';

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
            hosting.searchResults = data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Eror: ', response);
        });

    }
```

And this returns something like this when you search mydomains.com:

```
{"mydomains.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"}}
```

I don't understand how I would access the status string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log(data["mydomains.com"].status);
```

See it working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n6jqbcp9/

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the JSON to a JavaScript object.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Access the property `status`:

```
status = data["mydomains.com"]["status"]
```